# Converting VB. Net to C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datediff

I'm having trouble converting VB.Net to C#.Net. There is DateDiff() function in the code, and I'm having trouble to find the equivalent function in C#.
My code in VB is below:

```vb
'If the differnce between Now and the files header date >1 (day,week or year) then
If DateDiff(sDateInterval, dFileDate, Now) >= 1 Then
    Return True 'File over write is necessary 
Else
    Return False 'File over write is not necessary 
End If
```

Comment: Try [Telerik converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Answer (score 3):

DateDiff doesn't exist in C#, you simply subtract two dates:

```
DateTime date1 = somevalue;
DateTime date2 = someothervalue;

TimeSpan difference = date2 - date1;
```

So you can then retrieve, for example, `difference.TotalSeconds`.

See the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.90).aspx) for more information.

If you want to maintain the same interval functionality, there's nothing to stop you referencing `Microsoft.VisualBasic` and using the method you already do: [DateAndTime.DateDiff  MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127413(v=vs.110).aspx)